# How can I get notified whenever a UITextFeild's text changes, either by code or by user?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview

Normally we get notified of UITextField's text change by `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`、`editingDidChange:`、`textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` etc. But none of them gets fired when UITextField is changed by code, like `textField.text  = @"";`

I found that more than often I need a callback that fires both by code and user. For example, when I need to validate input and enable/disable submit button accordingly, when I need to change the height of UITextView to fit its content...

Right now I have to explicitly call the handlers. Is there any way can save me from the trouble? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nope, what you are doing is what you need to do. This is a good thing otherwise you could have problem with recursion.

Comment: I understand. Thans @rmaddy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ...

1.Take a global variable of UITextfield

2.Give tags to your textfield

3.And assign the Variable in any textfield delegate method and use it as you want.

check this eg.

```
@interface ViewController ()

{
 UITextField * actvieField;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.firstTextField.tag = 1;
  self.secondTextField.tag = 2;
  self.thirdTextField.tag = 3;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
  actvieField = textField;
 if (actvieField.tag == 1)
{
   //Do what you want 
}

  return YES;
}
```

Comment: None of this has anything to do with the question.

Comment: he asked about validating, and enabling disabling submit button. I have used this and it worked for me. @rmaddy

Comment: Yes, but the question is not about how to perform those actions. The OP already knows how to do those things. Have another read of the question. It's about trying to have the text field's delegate methods called when the text field's text is directly set via code.